# Possible JQuery class selector bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an ajax call that returns a HTML fragment.  I am trying to select a div in that fragment before rendering.

An example of the HTML:

```
<div class="event-detail repBy-container">
    <div class="copy">.....</div>
    <div class="links">
       ....
    </div>
    <div class="contacts">
      <div class="name-brand">....</div><div class="details">...., <a href="mailto:...@....">...</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem:

```
function ajaxReturn(data) {
   alert($(data).find('.event-detail').length); <-- Returns 0
   alert($(data).find('.copy').length); <-- Returns 1
}
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) gets *descendants* only, not from the current level, you'd need [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get items from the current set (which is the root of what you returned), like this:

```
function ajaxReturn(data) {
   alert($(data).filter('.event-detail').length); //<-- Returns 1
   alert($(data).find('.copy').length); //<-- Returns 1
}
```

If you want [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to work in both cases, add the content to a parent container, like this:

```
function ajaxReturn(data) {
   var parent = $("<div />").append(data);
   alert(parent.filter('.event-detail').length); //<-- Returns 1
   alert(parent.find('.copy').length); //<-- Returns 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it was driving me nuts

Answer (score 5):

This is the expected behavior.

- You are searching for `.event-detail` under your div and there isn't any.
- You are searching for `.copy` under your div and there is one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is being passed into the `ajaxReturn` function. ie what does `data` contain?

If it contains the HTML you quoted then this is expected behaviour. This is because the `.find()` method searches *within* the current context, not including it. If the outer div in your example is the outer div in `data` then `.find()` will be searching for `.event-detail` *inside* of that div.